# How do I block access for users on domain to "install this site as app" from edge?

Tags: registry, microsoft-edge, group-policy

How can I block this function in edge? Is there a reg key or group policy or anything that can help with this?

If you click the 3 dots top right of edge, go to apps, you can install any site as an app.

Any ideas?

AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

---

Answer (score 0):

Currently, there is no registry/group policy to disable the "install this site as app" function in Edge.

You could follow this [opening feature request](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/enterprise/completely-disable-apps-in-edge-via-group-policy/m-p/3023373) if there are any updates.

Of course, you could also submit a Feature Request through the browser ("..." menu > Help and feedback > Send feedback) which can help the team prioritize.

Thanks for your understanding.